# How to optimize checking for boundaries in regular expression?

Tags: regex, performance, optimization, conditional-statements

I am writing a programming language and creating my own regular expression implementation. I want to take the [BaseChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) block, which has a bunch of ranges:

```
BaseChar       ::=      [#x0041-#x005A] | [#x0061-#x007A] | [#x00C0-#x00D6] | [#x00D8-#x00F6] | [#x00F8-#x00FF] | [#x0100-#x0131] | [#x0134-#x013E] | [#x0141-#x0148] | [#x014A-#x017E] | [#x0180-#x01C3] | [#x01CD-#x01F0] | [#x01F4-#x01F5] | [#x01FA-#x0217] | [#x0250-#x02A8] | [#x02BB-#x02C1] | #x0386 | [#x0388-#x038A] | #x038C | [#x038E-#x03A1] | [#x03A3-#x03CE] | [#x03D0-#x03D6] | #x03DA | #x03DC | #x03DE | #x03E0 | [#x03E2-#x03F3] | [#x0401-#x040C] | [#x040E-#x044F] | [#x0451-#x045C] | [#x045E-#x0481] | [#x0490-#x04C4] | [#x04C7-#x04C8] | [#x04CB-#x04CC] | [#x04D0-#x04EB] | [#x04EE-#x04F5] | [#x04F8-#x04F9] | [#x0531-#x0556] | #x0559 | [#x0561-#x0586] | [#x05D0-#x05EA] | [#x05F0-#x05F2] | [#x0621-#x063A] | [#x0641-#x064A] | [#x0671-#x06B7] | [#x06BA-#x06BE] | [#x06C0-#x06CE] | [#x06D0-#x06D3] | #x06D5 | [#x06E5-#x06E6] | [#x0905-#x0939] | #x093D | [#x0958-#x0961] | [#x0985-#x098C] | [#x098F-#x0990] | [#x0993-#x09A8] | [#x09AA-#x09B0] | #x09B2 | [#x09B6-#x09B9] | [#x09DC-#x09DD] | [#x09DF-#x09E1] | [#x09F0-#x09F1] | [#x0A05-#x0A0A] | [#x0A0F-#x0A10] | [#x0A13-#x0A28] | [#x0A2A-#x0A30] | [#x0A32-#x0A33] | [#x0A35-#x0A36] | [#x0A38-#x0A39] | [#x0A59-#x0A5C] | #x0A5E | [#x0A72-#x0A74] | [#x0A85-#x0A8B] | #x0A8D | [#x0A8F-#x0A91] | [#x0A93-#x0AA8] | [#x0AAA-#x0AB0] | [#x0AB2-#x0AB3] | [#x0AB5-#x0AB9] | #x0ABD | #x0AE0 | [#x0B05-#x0B0C] | [#x0B0F-#x0B10] | [#x0B13-#x0B28] | [#x0B2A-#x0B30] | [#x0B32-#x0B33] | [#x0B36-#x0B39] | #x0B3D | [#x0B5C-#x0B5D] | [#x0B5F-#x0B61] | [#x0B85-#x0B8A] | [#x0B8E-#x0B90] | [#x0B92-#x0B95] | [#x0B99-#x0B9A] | #x0B9C | [#x0B9E-#x0B9F] | [#x0BA3-#x0BA4] | [#x0BA8-#x0BAA] | [#x0BAE-#x0BB5] | [#x0BB7-#x0BB9] | [#x0C05-#x0C0C] | [#x0C0E-#x0C10] | [#x0C12-#x0C28] | [#x0C2A-#x0C33] | [#x0C35-#x0C39] | [#x0C60-#x0C61] | [#x0C85-#x0C8C] | [#x0C8E-#x0C90] | [#x0C92-#x0CA8] | [#x0CAA-#x0CB3] | [#x0CB5-#x0CB9] | #x0CDE | [#x0CE0-#x0CE1] | [#x0D05-#x0D0C] | [#x0D0E-#x0D10] | [#x0D12-#x0D28] | [#x0D2A-#x0D39] | [#x0D60-#x0D61] | [#x0E01-#x0E2E] | #x0E30 | [#x0E32-#x0E33] | [#x0E40-#x0E45] | [#x0E81-#x0E82] | #x0E84 | [#x0E87-#x0E88] | #x0E8A | #x0E8D | [#x0E94-#x0E97] | [#x0E99-#x0E9F] | [#x0EA1-#x0EA3] | #x0EA5 | #x0EA7 | [#x0EAA-#x0EAB] | [#x0EAD-#x0EAE] | #x0EB0 | [#x0EB2-#x0EB3] | #x0EBD | [#x0EC0-#x0EC4] | [#x0F40-#x0F47] | [#x0F49-#x0F69] | [#x10A0-#x10C5] | [#x10D0-#x10F6] | #x1100 | [#x1102-#x1103] | [#x1105-#x1107] | #x1109 | [#x110B-#x110C] | [#x110E-#x1112] | #x113C | #x113E | #x1140 | #x114C | #x114E | #x1150 | [#x1154-#x1155] | #x1159 | [#x115F-#x1161] | #x1163 | #x1165 | #x1167 | #x1169 | [#x116D-#x116E] | [#x1172-#x1173] | #x1175 | #x119E | #x11A8 | #x11AB | [#x11AE-#x11AF] | [#x11B7-#x11B8] | #x11BA | [#x11BC-#x11C2] | #x11EB | #x11F0 | #x11F9 | [#x1E00-#x1E9B] | [#x1EA0-#x1EF9] | [#x1F00-#x1F15] | [#x1F18-#x1F1D] | [#x1F20-#x1F45] | [#x1F48-#x1F4D] | [#x1F50-#x1F57] | #x1F59 | #x1F5B | #x1F5D | [#x1F5F-#x1F7D] | [#x1F80-#x1FB4] | [#x1FB6-#x1FBC] | #x1FBE | [#x1FC2-#x1FC4] | [#x1FC6-#x1FCC] | [#x1FD0-#x1FD3] | [#x1FD6-#x1FDB] | [#x1FE0-#x1FEC] | [#x1FF2-#x1FF4] | [#x1FF6-#x1FFC] | #x2126 | [#x212A-#x212B] | #x212E | [#x2180-#x2182] | [#x3041-#x3094] | [#x30A1-#x30FA] | [#x3105-#x312C] | [#xAC00-#xD7A3]
```

And convert it into the most optimal conditional branching. Right now, it's as if it does this:

```
if (x > 10 && x < 20) {
  return true
}

if (x > 30 && x < 40) {
  return true
}

if (x > 50 && x < 60) {
  return true
}

// 100 more range checks...

return false
```

Should I just do the if/then for each range, or is there some magic trick to making it more optimized, so if we have a value that matches the last item in the range list it doesn't have to check everything preceding it? Are there any special techniques to apply here for optimization?

This range `BaseChar` thing is per character, so if our character matched the last item in the pattern, and we had a string of 10000 items, it would do 100 * 10000 conditionals (assuming there are 100 patterns), instead of just 1 * 10000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the result with conditionals like this is not efficient, especially when there is a lot of ranges to check. Condition are slow when they cannot be predicted by the processors (eg. random/data-dependent behaviour) or when there is too much of them (CPU predictors have a cache to remember if a condition often succeed/fail but this cache is quite small). In average, half the condition will be executed if the distribution of probability of the branch taken is uniform, or possibly a bit less if ranges are carefully chosen (the more frequent must appear first to cut the computation off).

One solution to speed up this is to use a **lookup table** (LUT). Lookup tables are great to improve the throughput of this computation if it is done in a loop, but they can also introduce a high-latency overhead when the code is rarely executed. The idea is to precompute an array of boolean values for each cell representing the `x` value. A first naive try is to create an array of boolean of size 0x10000. The resulting code would be just `return lut[x];` where for example `lut[0] == false`, `lut[10] == false`, `lut[11] == true`, etc.

The LUT must be kept small. Indeed, **the bigger the LUT, the slower the computation** (due to the additional overhead to keep the LUT in cache and possibly load it from RAM, generate it and so on). A first optimization is to generate a LUT of size `0x2200` (8 times smaller) and check it only if `x < 0x2000` (covering >95% of the tested ranges) which should be very frequent. Otherwise, the <5% remaining ranges are tested using the initial slow method. The resulting code looks like this:

```cpp
if(x < 0x2000)
    return lut[x];
return x == 0x2126 || x > x212A && x < 0x212B || ...;
```

Another possible optimization is to compress the LUT using **bit packing**. The idea is to pack 8 booleans per bytes so that the LUT can take only 1 KB (on a mainstream platform). If your target language is C++, please note that `std::vector<bool>` already implement this. Otherwise, the generation of the LUT must be modified and `lut[x]` should be replaced by `(lut[x >> 3] >> (x & 0x07)) & 0x01`. This may or may not be faster regarding the use-case.

Finally, **SIMD instructions** can be used to strongly speed up the computation. Indeed, almost x86-64 processors provide the SSE instruction set capable of computing 16 bytes per instruction or 8 16-bit values. The newer AVX/AVX2 instruction sets available on most recent x86-64 processor is capable of computing twice the amount of data per instruction. The very recent AVX-512 instruction set available only on few very-recent x86-64 processor can  is capable of computing twice the amount of data per instruction compared to AVX/AVX2 (so 4 times more than SSE). This strategy is especially good if you know most character lies in a specific range: for example if most character are ASCII ones, then you can very quickly check if 16/32/64 characters are ASCII ones and perform the range checks fully in SIMD only one the ASCII range, and otherwise you can fallback on a more expensive computation (possibly using a LUT or still SIMD instructions).

I think using a (possibly compressed) LUT is the best strategy in your case as the method is relatively simple (compared to using SIMD instruction) and should already be much faster than the original solution.